# Angular app doesnt show any either but the app doesnt load

Tags: angular, local-storage

I am building a Todo app in angular. 
The app was working fine until I added localstorage stuffs.
Can you say what could have went wrong.
Below is the service file.
The app adds task, deletes task, marks tasks as completed , filters tasks n so on

Expected. The app should perform all the above tasks
Actual: the localhost:4200 keep reloading ,but the app doesnt open

todo.service.ts

```
export class TodoService {
todoTitle: string = '';
idForTodo: number;
filter: string = 'all';
anyRemainingModel: boolean = true;


constructor() {
let todos = this.getTodos();

  if (todos.length == 0) {
    this.idForTodo = 0;
  } else {
    let maxId = todos[todos.length-1].id;
    this.idForTodo = maxId + 1;
  }}

public getTodos(): Todo[] {
  let localStorageItem = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('todos'));
  return localStorageItem == null ? [] : localStorageItem.todos;
}

addTodo(todoTitle: string): void {
if (todoTitle.trim().length === 0) {
  return;
}
let todos = this.getTodos();
todos.unshift({
  id: this.idForTodo,
  title: todoTitle,
  completed: false,
  editing: false
})
this.setLocalStorageTodos(todos);
this.idForTodo++;
}

this.anyRemainingModel = this.anyRemaining();
todo.editing = false;
}

deleteTodo(id: number): void {
let todos = this.getTodos();
todos = todos.filter(todo => todo.id !== id);
this.setLocalStorageTodos(todos);
}

remaining(): number {
let todos = this.getTodos();
return todos.filter(todo => !todo.completed).length;
}

atLeastOneCompleted(): boolean {
let todos = this.getTodos();
return todos.filter(todo => todo.completed).length > 0;
}

clearCompleted(): void {
 let todos = this.getTodos();
todos = todos.filter(todo => !todo.completed);
}

checkAllTodos(): void {
let todos = this.getTodos();
todos.forEach(todo => todo.completed = (<HTMLInputElement>event.target).checked)
this.anyRemainingModel = this.anyRemaining();
}



todosFiltered(): Todo[] {
let todos = this.getTodos();
if (this.filter === 'all') {
  return todos;
} else if (this.filter === 'active') {
  return todos.filter(todo => !todo.completed);
} else if (this.filter === 'completed') {
  return todos.filter(todo => todo.completed);
}

return todos;
}
private setLocalStorageTodos(todos: Todo[]): void {
  localStorage.setItem('todos', JSON.stringify({ todos: todos }));
 }
}
```

Comment: You probably have a console error.. You should check that.

Comment: seems like code isn't formatted well, I don't see the closing and openings are done correctly, and I didn't see the code block for anyRemaining() method

Comment: And also in checkAllTodos, which element should be considered as a target, as it is not receiving any parameter as the event, but it's being typecast to <HTMLInputElement>

Comment: Just set some breakpoints in your code and go through...